# Android - consume REST API with Cookie Authentification

Tags: android, rest, cookies, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to build a client for a REST API, which uses for Authentification Username, Password and a CSFR-Token send via Cookie. The API is build on the Django Framework, it has a nice description on how exactly the [Cookie-Auth for CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) is working.

I did a lot of research on Android as REST Client and found a lot of examples, but none with Cookie handling. So I struggled for 3 days with [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) and [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), which are often considered to be "easy to use", but I'm not very experienced and had really trouble with it. And I never got Cookie auth working.

Can anybody help me, on how to consume a REST API with Cookie Auth? Or which library is the most easy one to deal with this?

Thanks!

*PS: Forgive me to not post source-code snippets, but its so messed and spread over files: I don't even know how to organize the code for the API-handling. I'm at the very beginning here... :-(*

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply use token authentication?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[JShare](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare) is good Android library. It uses REST protocol and supports different authentications